# VS 2008 favorite projects list

Tags: visual-studio-2008, project, projects

I have a Folder with about **1000 Projects**.
So to open one, it's not that easy with this amount.

`Recent projects` are very useful feature, what I need is something like **favorite projects**.

Comment: Interestingly enough, I think that VS 2010 accommodates this out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty crazy. I suggest you start using folders to create a hierarchy, that's what they are for.

If you have a religious objection to that (or if there is some factor that prevents you from doing this, like build dependancies that would break if you moved them and would be too time consuming to fix), you could create a folder with shortcuts to the projects you care most about.

Comment: 'create a folder with shortcuts to the projects you care most about' is a wonderful response :)

Comment: Glad it helped :-) I wish I could suggest something better ... it got me wondering if there was an easy way to customise / roll your own the "Start" page in VS (and it doesn't look like I'm the only one to search for that) but curiously seem so, at least not in a documented way.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the idea of a folder with shortcuts, but if you are using Vista (or 7 I believe), just use the "Favorites" pane in the left side of the Windows Explorer to manage a set of current favorite folders. Those favorites share that space with the folder structure, but are often minimized and ignored.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on that has a "Favorite Solutions" tool [MZTools](http://www.mztools.com/v6/features.aspx).

Its has a number of other tools that come in handy.  Things like "Favorite Code Elements", "TabIndex Assistant", "Control Name Assistant" and "Control Explorer".